# Node module importing functions with type declarations

Tags: node.js, expo, node-modules

I'm trying to create a monorepo to use with an Expo project. For sake of simplicity, Im including only the info I think you need to understand what I do.

#### File structure

```
├── monorepo
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── myapp
│   │   │   └── App.tsx
│   ├── packages
│   │   │── mylib
│   │   │   │── package.json
│   │   │   │── index.ts
│   │   │   │── index.d.ts
│   │   │   │── test.js
```

#### myapp/App.tsx

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { testing } from "mylib"; << This does not import the function

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{testing}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

#### mylib/package.json

```
{
  "name": "mylib",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

#### mylib/index.ts

```
export default "hello from mylib";
```

#### mylib/index.d.ts

```
export * from "./test";
```

#### mylib/test.js

```
export function testing() {
  return "hello";
}
```

In App.tsx, if I do `import testing from "mylib"` without the curly brackets, it will treat `testing` as the default export of `mylib/index.ts` and print "hello from mylib" on the screen.
Next, I want to actually import the testing function, so I do `import { testing } from "mylib"`, but that does not recognize the `testing` function.

How do I properly import a function from a package? What am I missing?

## UPDATE

I believe the issue I'm having has to do with the fact that I am actually importing from `index.ts`, regardless of my declaration file. Since `index.ts` has only a default export of a value, it does not know what I want to import from there. I need to figure out how declaration files work with the actual javascript functional code.

For example, if I change `index.ts` to `export * from "./test";` and edit `App.tsx` as:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { testing } from "mylib";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{testing()}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

then it will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can only import from a package name if it is an installed package in the `node_modules` directory. In your case, you have to import from the relative file path like this:

```
import { testing } from "../../packages/mylib/test";
```

Comment: That's incorrect. Node module resolution will search up the root path. But it's not important in this case, since, as I wrote, I use a monorepo and I install my packages with yarn. Also, as mentioned, I don't have a problem accessing the module. I have a problem accessing a specific function. It's about the proper way to export/import it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share a [great article about node modules and types](https://medium.com/jspoint/typescript-module-system-5022cac310f6)

It helped me understand what I was not getting. Essentially, I was treating the type declaration file as the entry point file which is supposed to export functions. In my case, my functions already had type definitions, so adding a types declaration file to the module was not even needed.